# ckedtitor adds chrome://hdv/content/hdv.js text to source

Tags: ckeditor

Every time I open ckeditor (all versions), the editor adds the following line to the source:

```
<script charset="UTF-8" src="chrome://hdv/content/hdv.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

This happens in all versions of Chrome, Firefox and IE.

Any idea on why this is happening, and how to get rid of this bug/feature will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, it was caused by firefox plugin - you tube auto hd, uninstall it

here you have [link](https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/high-definition-video/reviews/)